# Export to CSV fails with UnicodeEncodeError using pymssql module

Tags: python-2.7, pymssql

I'm trying to execute a simple sql and write the results to CSV output. However, the code fails with:

```
<pymssql.Connection object at 0x01EF4AF8>
<_csv.writer object at 0x0B6C3270>
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\_WORKSPACE\ReportsInventory\CustomReports\CustomReports.py", line 38, in     <module>
f.writerow(row)
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\x96' in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The database I am running is against is: MSSQLSERVER. I've specified charset="ISO-8859-1" in the connect string. I understand that it is hitting a special character, but any idea on how to handle them so the insert can be successful?

Thanks in advance,
simak

My complete code is below:

```
import pymssql
import csv

import datetime 
import re
import sys
from config import config

user=r'user'
database = config['ProdDatabase']
connection = pymssql.connect(config['ProdHost'], user, config['ProdPassword'],    database,charset="ISO-8859-1")
connLog = pymssql.connect(config['ProdHost'], user, config['ProdPassword']
print connection

cursor = connection.cursor()

query = """ SELECT dbname,ReportType,ReportID,Report,ReportDriver,FilteredColumn,Filter,FilteredConditionValue     from tempReports """

cursor.execute(query)


data=cursor.fetchall()

f =    csv.writer(open("C:\\_WORKSPACE\\ReportsInventory\\CustomReports\\customreports.csv","w"))
print f
for row in data:
    f.writerow(row)
cursor.close()
f.close()
connection.close()
```

Comment: why not ignore 'ascii'? Doesn't that help?

Answer (score 0):

```
data=cursor.fetchall()

# encode characters
data =[c.encode('ascii','ignore') for c in data]

f = csv.writer(open("C:\\_WORKSPACE\\ReportsInventory\\CustomReports\\customreports.csv","w"))
print f
for row in data:
    f.writerow(row)
cursor.close()
f.close()
connection.close()
```